Firestore setoptions merge true and update overriding even other fields
I am trying to update my firestore doc from different screens. But when i use .set with merge true or even use update the previous values gets assigned to null. Please help me to sort out this problem
addDataToDBSubCollection(String collectionName, String docID,
      String subCollection, String subDocID, Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    bool lCheck = false;
    try {
      lCheck = await _db
          .collection(collectionName)
          .doc(docID)
          .collection(subCollection)
          .doc(subDocID)
          .set(data, SetOptions(merge: true))
          .then((value) {
        print("true");
        return true;
      });
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      // Caught an exception from Firebase.
      print("Failed with error '${e.code}': ${e.message}");
      lCheck = false;
    }
    return lCheck;
  }
updateDataToDBSubCollection(String collectionName, String docID,
      String subCollection, String subDocID, Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    bool lCheck = false;
    try {
      lCheck = await _db
          .collection(collectionName)
          .doc(docID)
          .collection(subCollection)
          .doc(subDocID)
          .update(data)
          .then((value) {
        print("true");
        return true;
      });
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      // Caught an exception from Firebase.
      print("Failed with error '${e.code}': ${e.message}");
      lCheck = false;
    }
    return lCheck;
  }

This is the way i am assigning the values from different screens
Screen1
_checkTimingsModel = CheckTimingsModel(
                                id: id,
                                userName: "Pulkit",
                                checkedInAt: _homeController.cInDateTime,
                                checkedOutAt: null);

Screen 2
_checkTimingsModel = CheckTimingsModel(
                                oilImagePath: oilURL,
                                coolantImagePath: coolantURL,
                                weeklyTaskDate: DateTime.now(),
                              );

And then i called the methods
_dbServices.addDataToDBSubCollection(
                                    "users",
                                    phn!,
                                    "checkTimeDetails",
                                    id,
                                    _checkTimingsModel!.toMap());

This funtion when called on Screen 2 is replacing the values of screen 1 with null and screen 2 values get inserted. Pleas help me to resolve this problem.

The problem is likely in the data that you pass in (as this API is pretty well vetted by now). What does _checkTimingsModel!.toMap() return? Better yet: can you show code that reproduces the problem and is just a single API call to Firestore with just hard-coded values? That makes it much more likely that someone will spot what's going on. Also see: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Actually ijust checked _checkTimingsModel!.toMap() returns null value for other fields. How shall i create my model so that only the fields that has to be updated gets affected.

All field that are present in the map will be updated with the value that is present in that map. So you'll have to ensure the map only includes the fields you want to actually update. If you're having trouble with that, edit your quesditon to show what _checkTimingsModel looks like and how it's initialized (as asked above already).
